# android socket connection timed out

Tags: android, sockets, client-server, connection-timeout

**background** i'm trying to create an android client application for my java server and make them communicate using TCP sockets.

**what works** my app works when i run it on android device emulator

**what doesn't work** when i run the app on my phone i get connection time out when creating the socket.

**the exception** java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 9111): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

the server and mobile device are connected to the same wifi network and i have turned off the firewall on my laptop (where i run the server)

what could be the cause of this?, thanks anyone for help

server

```
public class HelpMeServer {
public final static int port=9111;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Database db=new Database();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Listening on port "+port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: "+port);
        System.exit(1);
    }

   while(true)
   {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        ClientThread t=new ClientThread(clientSocket,db);
        t.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
   }
}
}
```

main activity

```
 public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

private EditText view_email;
private EditText view_password;
TextView result;
ConnectionHandler conhandler;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    view_email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    view_password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
}
public void login(View view)
{    
    String email=view_email.getText().toString();
    String password=view_password.getText().toString();
    ConnectionHandler c=new ConnectionHandler();
    c.execute(new String[]{"login",email,password});
    try {
        String response=c.get();
        if(response.equals("login successful"))
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        result.setText(response);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        result.setText("err");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result.setText("err");
    }
}
}
```

async activity that starts the socket

```
public class ConnectionHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

public static final String serverip = "10.0.2.2";
public static final int serverport = 9111;
Socket s;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... lines)
{
Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Creating Socket");
try {
    s = new Socket(serverip, serverport);
        Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Created Socket");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Cannot create Socket "+e.toString());
    }
        if (s.isConnected()) {
        try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Socket created, Streams assigned");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Cannot assign Streams, Socket not connected");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
    Log.i("AsyncTank", "doInBackgoung: Cannot assign Streams, Socket is closed");
        }
        for (String line:lines)
        {
            writeToStream(line);
        }
        String result=readFromStream();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked firewall-rules for the "server" computer or any routers?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serverip = "10.0.2.2" try entering your PC IP address if the server is running on your PC.